# How should I serialize dynamic form elements in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC 5 project and part of that is a registration. Presently the form submits using the standard form submit action and my model binder does its job gloriously and all is good.

However, I now need to add a dynamic element to my form such that a user needs to be able to add on the fly invitations to add team members via a textbox for an email address and a dropdown list for that team members role... and an *add another* button to add another textbox and dropdown list for the next team member... and the next... ad infinitum...

Upon form submission, my model binder is going to fall over and not know what to do with these dynamic elements, so I need suggestions for how to get my model binder to deserialize these items into an array of email & role (role binds to an enum).

I've had it suggested that client side script can catch the submission and serialize the items to a text string and put that in a hidden form field that I can then deserialize manually on my controller action, which seems like it'll work okay, but it feels dirty.

What is the most straightforward way of achieving this? Is there anything built into .NET that will automatically handle this somehow if I configure my view correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your model can store your "dynamic" fields in a collection like:

```
public List<string> Emails { get; set; }
```

In your view you just create subsequent indexed names (exact naming depends on how you're generating this new fields):

```
model.Emails[0] // name="Emails[0]"
model.Emails[1] // name="Emails[1]"
```

In your controller action, there should be nothing special the model binder has to do.  It will easily be able to handle the collections.

Comment: At form generation time, there is never a list... the list is created client side. So when the list comes back it's been populated as it were from scratch. A list of email addresses with their corresponding roles which then needs to be bound by my model binder. So it's a list of complex objects.

Answer (score 0):

There is an old article from Phil Haack about binding to a List:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

I guess you could add a ICollection<Invitation>-Property to your model and set the Name of the form fields as explained in the article.

Although personally I would bind the data to a JavaScript-ViewModel and post JSON back to the Server using Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Upon clicking the "Add more" button, simply inject the textbox and dropdown and let the form serialize like usual.

On the server, accept a list of `invitations`:

```
public class Invitation
{
   public string EmailAddresss {get; set;}
   public int InvitationType {get; set; }
}


public ActionResult Register(MyCurrentModel dto, Invitation[] invitations)
{
   //..
}
```

Comment: Wow, I'll give this a try. If it's really that simple, that's great! Thanks!